# NestJS: organizing providers to be shared among several controllers

Tags: nestjs

I have seen the following project structure so far:

```
src
- cats
  - dto
    - create-cat.dto.ts
  - interfaces
    - cat.interface.ts
  - cats.controller.ts
  - cats.module.ts
  - cats.service.ts
- app.module.ts
- main.ts
```

The cats module units related functionalities (service and controller) and it makes sense.

Let's now imagine we have 2 parts of our application:

- Customer portal for users to manage their cats.
- Admin panel for admins to manage all cats.

Each part needs its own controller, but I feel like both controllers should use the same service. What would be a proper way to achieve this functionality?

Is it a good idea to make a module for service and 2 modules for controllers importing it? Or maybe 1 module for both controllers?
Another option, which comes to my mind, is just to make a controllers directory and make each controller (admin and portal) part of the same cats module, but it's then difficult to manage it with swagger docs.

Answer (score 0):

`Admins` and `Customer portal` both of them have the nature of user so you need one module (users.module).

The difference between them (admin and customer portal) are their role, your system needs two role management (like admin, and user) with using `UseGuards`, so based on the role, they have access to their own routes of user.module and in the user module you can use the `cats.service`

Comment: It makes sense, but the DTOs for creating/updating a cat are different. Admins in the Admin panel are allowed to edit more fields. Also, ideally, I would like to group endpoints for Admin Panel and Customer Portal - first of all, to be used in apps through `/api/admin` and `api/portal`, secondly to keep things organized in swagger. I have currently achieved this by making a `ControllersModule`, not sure if it's a good approach though.

Comment: For small project and student project use this aproach, but for large project with dynamic roles never use this approch

Comment: Why not? I can add role guards in each controller separately.